# Gradle javaexec fails with useless error message

Tags: cucumber, gradle

When I execute the task below I get a pointer to the javaexec line with the following unhelpful message:

```
Process 'command '/home/dws/bin/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I get the same message no matter what is in the javaexec{} command.  I've changed the main class to a non-existant class.  I've changed the classpath.  I've changed the args.

Does anyone know what Gradle is complaining about?

```
task execCucTests() {

    dependsOn compileGroovy, compileTestGroovy
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
            args = ['-f', 'pretty', '--glue', 'src/test/groovy/com/icd/cucumber/steps', 'src/test/features']

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [JavaExec task type](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html)? You don't appear to be doing anything in your example that can't be done in the task. While it wouldn't shock me to find out the same basic call is eventually being made, maybe you'll get a slightly better error message. It also (in my opinion) looks a lot slicker and is easier to read.